# How to get dates of next 7 weekdays

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to get the dates of next 7 week days. I am able to get next days but unable to skip weekends and holidays. how can i acheive this. can someone please guide me.

I have tried this so far.

```
 constructor(private calendar: NgbCalendar) {
    let d1 = any;
    let d2: any;
    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      d1 = calendar.getNext(calendar.getToday(), 'd', i);
      d2 = d1.day + '.' + d1.month + '.' + d1.year;
      this.days.push(d2);
    }
    console.log(this.days)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend swapping out your for loop for a while loop. You'd only push the day to this.days and increment your iterator if d1.getDay() !== 0 || 6

As far as omitting 'holidays', that will vary dramatically depending on what country/culture you are in and what holidays are observed. You'd probably need an array of holidays you want to omit and add that to your conditional statement.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [moment weekdays](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/listing-months-weekdays/)

```
weekArray = moment.weekdays()
```